# Layout Issue In Java

Tags: java, layout, jpanel

I am making a project in java and I am trying to set the layout of the JPanel That I Have created when I create It, I don`t really know what is causing this issue of it being underlined red.
I am using NetBeans.
Here is the code that i am trying to use for it:
(Import Class):

```
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
```

(JPanel Code):

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BoxLayout());
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you imported `JPanel` ? or `BoxLayout` ?

Comment: I did, I edited This and fixed it

Comment: @ThomasPhillips, so that means the question is no longer relevant? Was this a typo?

Comment: No, What I meant is i fixed the mistake it the Question.  Not In the code.

Comment: @ThomasPhillips, so then, what's the error on that red line is saying?

Comment: This Question Is No Longer relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html), BoxLayout requires two parameters in the constructor (the `new Boxlayout()` part):

```
BoxLayout(Container target, int axis)
Creates a layout manager that will lay out components along the given axis.
Parameters:
    target - the container that needs to be laid out
    axis - the axis to lay out components along. Can be one of: BoxLayout.X_AXIS, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS or BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS
```

You'll have to specify both of them to make it work.

Edit: You can find information on what each axis does in the linked documentation.